# INSERT INTO SELECT doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert

```
INSERT INTO `competitions` (`name`) VALUES SELECT `name` FROM `competitions`
```

Produces the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT `name` FROM `competitions`' at line 1

I'm probably overlooking something trivial but I really don't see what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: remove `VALUES`. See syntax: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct syntax is

```
INSERT INTO `competitions` (`name`) SELECT `name` FROM `competitions`
```

Refer to:  [INSERT ... SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-select.html)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `VALUES` from your query!

The syntax of this statement is:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_temp2 (fld_id)
    SELECT tbl_temp1.fld_order_id
    FROM tbl_temp1 WHERE tbl_temp1.fld_order_id > 100;
```

Right syntax will be:

```
INSERT INTO `competitions` (`name`)
    SELECT `name` FROM `competitions`
```